# C - load txt content into two dimentional array

Tags: c, arrays, file, io

This is my pattern txt:

```
##########
#1     # #
#   #    #
#     #  #
#        #
#        #
#  #2   ##
#        #
#    #   #
##########
```

I wanna load this line by line inside a two-dimentional array, like char board[10][10];

This is my loadFile Code:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(file_name,"r");
do{
    for(int a=0;a<10;a++){
        for(int b=0;b<10;b++){
            fscanf(fp,"%c",&board[a][b]);
        }
    }
}while(!feof(fp));
// test print for showing into console
for(int c=0;c<10;c++){
    for(int d=0;d<10;d++){
        printf("%s",board[c][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: What is your preference? I mean do you have any order of reading/writing this information to an array? If not, I would suggest preallocating a big 2d array (unless you know exactly how many characters you need to read), do a nested for loop, and doing fgetc() for each character and storing them to your array[i][j].

Comment: These pattern is from a file called "map.txt", i just try to create a simple pac-man game.... I wanna load this file contents into array.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to read in characters from a file and print them to the screen, for example?

Comment: this is my script 'FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen(file_name,"r");
 do{
  for(int a=0;a<10;a++){
   for(int b=0;b<10;b++){
    fscanf(fp,"%c",&board[a][b]);
   }
  }
 }while(!feof(fp));
 // test print for showing into console
 for(int c=0;c<10;c++){
  for(int d=0;d<10;d++){
   printf("%s",board[c][d]);
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
 fclose(fp);'

Comment: @user3658777 Don't post code on comments. Edit your question and add code there.

Comment: hmm? no NULL check for `fp`, `%s` for `board[c][d]` [Assuming 2D char array]...??? and what about reading `newline`?

Comment: What problem are you having with your current code? Also, you should check the return values of `fopen` and `fscanf`; those functions can fail.

Comment: I get this when i test debugging, https://www.dropbox.com/s/6q5koo3pbnxrxfg/out.png?dl=0

Comment: @user3658777 `fscanf` is not optimal for this, try using [fgetc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) instead. And remember that there are also linebreak characters that text file contains.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(file_name,"r");
for(int a=0;a<10;a++){
    for(int b=0;b<10;b++){
        fscanf(fp,"%c", &board[a][b]);
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%*c");//for skip newline
}
fclose(fp);
// test print
for(int c=0;c<10;c++){
    for(int d=0;d<10;d++){
        printf("%c", board[c][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```